# Hibernate Criteria Example query join

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a dao method named getByTemplate. There are two tables which are Student and School. There is a one-to-many relationship between this tables. What I want to do is;

```
Student student = new Student();
student.setSchool(mySchool);
myDao.getByTemplate(student);
```

But the problem is Hibernate ignores objects while querying. So this method returns all students from db. Is there any way to do this query using example model?

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public <T> List<T> getByTemplate(T templateEntity) {
    Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(templateEntity.getClass());
    criteria.add(Example.create(templateEntity));

    return criteria.list();
}
```

Comment: IMHO the hql join querys are a lot readable and easier to write than criterias...

Answer (score 0):

You should create to Examples and two createCriteria calls to use both Student and School:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public <T,U> List<T> getByTemplate(T templateEntity1, U templateEntity2) {
    Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession()
      .createCriteria(templateEntity1.getClass()).add(Example.create(templateEntity1))
      .createCriteria(templateEntity2.getClass()).add(Example.create(templateEntity2));
    return criteria.list();
}
```

And you can call it the following way:

```
myDao.getByTemplate(student, mySchool);
```